# 'This question has been - no more answers will be accepted' browser bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, notifications, ajax

I was about to post an answer, when a weird box that said 'This question has been' appeared.  I think it means to say 'This question has been deleted' or 'This question has been closed'.  Is this a bug or does it mean what it says?  I was using **FireFox v26.0** if that helps.[image: Bug Picture]

Comment: This comment has been - no more comments will be accepted.

Comment: Localization, it's always localization.

Comment: I accidentally a question.

Comment: This seems like some bad Stack Overflow post: `My question haz been. I cant answer`.

Comment: @Gilles only when it is not caching

Comment: Oscillation....

Comment: Why question no work?

Comment: "This question is undergoing an existential crisis…"

Comment: Yep, it was closed less than two minutes after being posted as can be seen in its [revisions list](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20914960/revisions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Localization bug strikes again. Fixed with build rev `2014.1.4.1822` on meta and `2014.1.4.1276` on sites.